# Form elements do not have associated labels

Tags: html, lighthouse

This test is failed by lighthouse because i have no label for input. I want the search field without label.

```
<form method="get" class="header-serc" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>search">
<input type="text" name="search" class="textbox" placeholder="Search">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should always have a label for the input. A placeholder is not the same as a label. It fails for a reason (accessibility for screen readers among others). If you do not want to SHOW the label then that is a bad practise... but you could hide it. Hope that helps.